# A term or word to express "someone or something itself"

Tags: single-word-requests

I seem to remember it's a two-word-term (not totally sure) like "____ self".

We all know that only when a subject has occurred before can we use reflexive pronouns like "itself". For example, "We introduced ourselves". So if I wanna ignore the subject, I can use "[verb]", + "[____ self]" to represent itself, himself, herself....

Can someone tell me the term I have forgotten?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the subject"? Can you provide some example sentences of where this might be used?

Comment: Thank u for comment. Eg. "xx self should recognize this situation" instead of "We ourselves should recognize this situation"

Comment: You're looking for a word you can put before "self," i.e. in place of the "xx", so that it will have the same meaning as "We ourselves"?

Comment: Yeah, thats right. What's more, 'xx self' can replace whatever you want like "we ourselves" and "he himself".

Comment: "They themselves"?

Comment: The closest I can get to understanding this is say 'Aloysius self-harms' for 'Aloysius deliberately injures himself'. The reflexive pronoun, not the subject noun /NP, is parked.

Comment: *oneself* ?  Can be *ownself* vernacularly.

Comment: You "wanna ignore the subject"? Please: want to. Someone or something itself: a proper person or a proper bath.

Comment: Thank you very much Edwin Ashworth. You helped me re-edit the body of this question. There're so many mistakes and I learnt a lot from them.